Is it possible to install newer kernels without knowing system password on Lubuntu if physical access is there?
I have installed Lubuntu with Home In a separate partition. The Home has a separate mount point and it was encrypted. It was all working. I need to provide the password for Home first then the system password was asked for.
I have done small updates but have not installed any newer versions like new LTS etc. The installation was very new.
When I started the system after a few days I felt something new.

The biggest problem was the cursor was not going to the input box to provide for Home encryption partition. I typed the password but it has not taken.

Also, below that keyboard sign used to come, and besides that "no" was always written. This time this "no" was missing.

I feared I lost the password. I was thinking of a fresh installation. Then, I noticed Advanced Options menu was not appearing during boot. But, it was coming now.

Also, "Ubuntu" word was visible. I knew Lubuntu is a Ubuntu type so I did not take it seriously. But, I have NOT noticed the word anywhere earlier in my installation.

Then I could try older kernels, and it worked. Then I saw "no" beside the keyword sign for encrypted Home partition.


So, my question is related to the Security point of view. Can someone install something that encapsulates the system so that they can read/watch me from a distance?
After that I could log in to the system, I uninstalled it by purging the kernels. I updated the grub.

LTS isn’t something you install after the fact you either installed a LTS version or you didn’t, so did you, if so what version? Your hit going to be able to place the kernel without at least root.

There is no way for someone at this site to know if your machine is compromised.  If you are concerned, since this is a new installation, 1. Make fresh Lubuntu installation media. 2. Remove the existing Linux partition, leaving it free space. 3. Reinstall Lubuntu de novo.
